# Replace matrix elements based on column and row names

Tags: r, matrix, replace

I have a matrix of elements with numeric values, e.g.:

```
> mtx <- as.matrix(read.csv("matrix.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1,sep = ","))
> head(mtx)

     BE   BG   EE   ES   FI
BE 0.00 0.75 0.17 0.28 0.48
BG 0.75 0.00 0.92 1.03 1.24
EE 0.17 0.92 0.00 0.11 0.31
ES 0.28 1.03 0.11 0.00 0.20
```

I want to replace values in certain elements with zero based on names of columns and rows. Namely, I want to have zero when column "BE" intersects with row "ES" and vice versa, i.e. when column "ES" intersects with row "BE", so I want to get:

```
     BE   BG   EE   ES   FI 
BE 0.00 0.75 0.17 0.00 0.00 
BG 0.75 0.00 0.92 1.03 1.24 
EE 0.17 0.92 0.00 0.11 0.31 
ES 0.00 1.03 0.11 0.00 0.00
```

I have to perform this operation for many matrices, which are larger than this example, so there are >150 pairs for which replacement is needed. Here's [data structure](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ag9E61lV4zhAe8pCwiHAGcwXbsDa9Gg1i-6j1JVV8GI/edit?usp=sharing). Replacement needed for: 
`c('BE', 'FI', 'FR', 'DE', 'IE', 'NL', 'NO', 'SE', 'CH', 'GB', 'DK','PT','ES')`

I have found function `replace`, but it works apparently only based on criteria applied to the values, not to the names of rows and columns of elements that contain them...

Comment: Try `mtx[c("BE", "ES"), c("ES", "BE")] <- 0`

Comment: or use matrix indexing: `mtx[rbind(c("BE", "ES"), c("ES", "BE"))] <- 0`. Take a look at `?"["`, it's worth reading two or three times.

Comment: thank you! The issue is that there are hundreds of such pairs, that's why I'm looking for something which can automate it

Comment: Typically, people request that you provide a reproducible example that illustrates your problem. Here, you should use `dput` on mtx and paste the results into your question. Second, you should include the additional information either by mentioning it in the text of your question and perhaps by adding a second pair in your example. Look into `?ncomb`. This may be helpful. Also `expand.grid`. It is not clear what your data structure for your hundreds of pairs is, so you should also provide this in your question.

Comment: thank you, I've adjusted the question accordingly

Answer (score 1):

As the diagonals are zero, we could subset the rows/columns and assign it to 0

```
 mtx[c("BE", "ES"), c("ES", "BE")] <- 0
```

Answer (score 0):

akrun's answer is great. I added my solution here and hope it helps.

The matrix can be manipulated by filtering rownames and colnames to a set of names.

For example:

```
a=matrix(1:9,3,3)
dimnames(a) <- list(c("x","y","z"),c("x","y","z"))
a[(rownames(a) %in% c("a")), colnames(a) %in% c("d")] <- 0
```

But I think you want to have zero in some diagonal positions; so the solution for that will be:

```
a <- matrix(1:9,3,3)
dimnames(a) <- list(c("x","y","z"),c("x","y","z"))

rows <- c("x","z")
ind <- which(rownames(a) %in% rows)

diag(a)[ind] <- 0
```